# passing non-model fields with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a situation in which I'm passing additional fields to form_for function, which don't belong to a model. Those fields are: redirect_to, redirect_time. I use those fields to know where to redirect the user after the form is successfully submitted - I don't store them, just read in the controller.

Now, everything is working perfectly when I have:

```
<%= form_for @mymodel .. %>
  <%= if defined?(redirect_to) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :redirect_to, redirect_to %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And read in controller:

```
def action
  if params['redirect_to']
    redirect_to params['redirect_to']
  end
end
```

But the problem occurs when the form has an error, Rails of course, won't pass those params that don't belong to the current resource.

Whats the most elegant way to deal with this situation in Rails to preserve those fields when form submission fails?

Thanks for help

Comment: Use virtual attributes in the model? Use a form model with a backing AR model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd be better off storing these variables within the `session` rather than the form. Firstly it will make them much harder to interfere with if people started poking about in the source of your web page, and secondly they'll be available to whatever action or controller you need them in once you're done with processing the submitted form.

Since they're not related to the form itself it feels much cleaner abstracting them outside of it.

Just set the session variables you need in the controller prior to rendering the form:

```
session[:redirect_to] = url_to_redirect_to_after_submitting_form
```

Then you can redirect there after saving the record in your create action:

```
def create
  # ... save record
  redirect_to session[:redirect_to]
end
```

Comment: Having a redirect based on a form value is a [security issue](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) unless you do some strict validation on the supplied path. This solution is much safer

Answer (score 2):

Passing non-model fields through ActiveRecord is poor solution to your problem of routing.

Keep to convention and use ActiveRecord as an interface to the state of your application data.